# How can a sub-object be pruned from a json object using jq?

Tags: json, edit, jq

In the following, I am trying to delete one of the two objects in the "bar" array, the one where "v" == 2:

```
{
  "foo": {},
  "bar": [
    {
      "v": 2
    },
    {
      "v": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I am able to first only keep the list, then delete the matching object:

```
.bar[] | select(.v ==2 | not)
```

returns:

```
{
  "v": 1
}
```

Is there a way to delete a sub-object to keep the enclosing object:

```
{
  "foo": {},
  "bar": [
    {
      "v": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of the given attempt, namely:

> .bar[] | select(.v ==2 | not)

you would use the `|=` operator, e.g.:

```
.bar |= map(select(.v ==2 | not))
```

Or simply:

```
 .bar |= map(select(.v != 2))
```

If you only wanted to delete the first match, you could write:

```
.bar |= (index({v:2}) as $i| .[:$i] + .[$i+1:])
```

or more robustly:

```
.bar |= (index({v:2}) as $i
  | if $i then .[:$i] + .[$i+1:] else . end)
```

or if you prefer:

```
.bar |= ( ([.[].v]|index(2)) as $i
  | if $i then del(.[$i]) else . end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `del` operator to delete the node you want:

```
<file jq 'del(.bar[] | select(.v==2))'
```